# Array issue with endbefore start in CPLEX

Tags: optimization, constraints, cplex, job-scheduling, constraint-programming

I am trying to add an Endbeforestartconstraint to my contrained programming problem. However, I receive an error saying that my end beforestart is not an array type. I do not understand this as I almost copied the constraint and data from the sched_seq example in CPLEX, I only changed it to integers.

What I try to accomplish with the constraint, is that task 3 and task 1 will be performed before task 2 will start.

How I can fix the array error for this constraint?

Please find below the relevant parts of my code

```
tuple Precedence {int pre;int post;};

{Precedence} Precedences = {<3,2>,<1,2>};

dvar interval task[j in Jobs] in release..due;
dvar interval opttask[j in Jobs][m in Machines] optional size duration[j][m];

dvar sequence tool[m in Machines] in all(j in Jobs) opttask[j][m]
```

```
dexpr int makespan = max(j in Jobs, m in Machines)(endOf(opttask[j][m]));
minimize makespan;
 
subject to {
  // Each job needs one unary resource of the alternative set s (28)
  forall(j in Jobs){
    alternative(task[j], all(m in Machines) opttask[j][m]);
     
    }     
  // No overlap on machines
  forall(j in Jobs)
    forall(p in Precedences)
    endBeforeStart(opttask[j][p.pre],opttask[j][p.post]);
   
   forall(m in Machines){
     noOverlap(tool[m],transitionTimes);
       }     
    
};

execute {
  writeln(task);
```

dat.

```
nbMachines = 2;
nbJobs = 3;


duration = [
        [5,6], 
        [4,4],
        [5,8]
            ];

release = 1;

due = 30;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your model, on ranges or on inverted indices.
Also, next time, please post a complete program showing the problem, not just a partial one, this may help you to get quicker answers.
A corrected program:

```
using CP;

int nbMachines = 2;
int nbJobs = 3;


range Machines = 0..nbMachines-1;
range Jobs = 0..nbJobs-1;

int duration[Jobs][Machines] = [
        [5,6], 
        [4,4],
        [5,8]
            ];

            
int release = 1;
int due = 30;

tuple Precedence {int pre;int post;};

{Precedence} Precedences = {<2,1>,<0,1>};

dvar interval task[j in Jobs] in release..due;
dvar interval opttask[j in Jobs][m in Machines] optional size duration[j][m];

dvar sequence tool[m in Machines] in all(j in Jobs) opttask[j][m];

dexpr int makespan = max(j in Jobs, m in Machines)(endOf(opttask[j][m]));
minimize makespan;
 
subject to {
  // Each job needs one unary resource of the alternative set s (28)
  forall(j in Jobs){
    alternative(task[j], all(m in Machines) opttask[j][m]);
     
    }     
  // No overlap on machines
  forall(m in Machines)
    forall(p in Precedences)
    endBeforeStart(opttask[p.pre][m],opttask[p.post][m]);
};

execute {
  writeln(task);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have values in p.pre or p.post that are outside of the array indexing range.

Comment: Hi @rdu , I have added the dat. file I used . Hope this makes it a bit more clear to you

Comment: What I do not understand is how the values in p.pre or p.post can be outside the array index as they simply represent a job which is within the range 1..nbjobs. The array size of precedence assumes on value representing pre and one value representing post.